# Get child Fragment from activity after creating it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to call a fragment's method from an Activity, so i use this kind of thing :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new DummyFragment()).commit();
((DummyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer)).method(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

My problem is that i get an exception :

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.app.DummyFragment.method(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.List)' on a null object reference`

I think i know what's the mistake : when i fetch the fragment, it's not created or accessible yet, so is there any way to make it work ? A listener for when the fragment is ready for example ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you missed to `commit()` the transaction

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new DummyFragment()).commit();
```

Edit:

add the line before `findFragmentById`

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()
```

Comment: Pleae check my edit, add the line `executePendingTransactions`